# I can't stop my web app sending values to my database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, visual-studio

So I am attempting to create an asp.net web app in c# using visual studio. One of my web pages has two radio buttons (add a parent & add a child) and depending on which one is selected, a number of text boxes will become visible and have to be filled in for registration. I have successfully connected my submit button to my database and the values entered in the text boxes are being sent, correctly, to the corresponding 'parents' & 'children' tables in my database.

The problem I am now having is that i'm trying to set it so that there has to be an entry in all of text boxes and if there aren't then a message box will appear telling the user that they need to fill out all of the fields. I have actually managed to get this to work, the issue I am having is that even though it tells you that you need to fill out all of the fields, it is still sending the values that were filled out to the database.

What I am wondering is if there is a way to not open the database connection if any of the text boxes are not filled out. I've attached my code below, thanks :).

```
protected void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data  Source=THEBEAST;Initial Catalog=newregDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
        {
            if (firstNameBox.Text == "" || surnameBox.Text == "" || dayDobList.Text == "" || monthDobList.Text == "" || yearDobList.Text == "" || genderList.Text == "" || postcodeBox.Text == "" || teleBox.Text == "" || emailBox.Text == "" || userBox.Text == "" || passwordBox.Text == "")
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Please ensure all fields have an entry');</script>");

            if (parentRadBtn.Checked)

            {
                SqlCommand pa = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO parent(parentID, firstname, surname, postcode, telephone, email, password) VALUES (@parentID, @firstname, @surname, @postcode, @telephone, @email, @password)", connect);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parentID", userBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstNameBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", surnameBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", postcodeBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telephone", teleBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordBox.Text);

                connect.Open();
                pa.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connect.Close();

                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                    userBox.Text = "";
                    firstNameBox.Text = "";
                    surnameBox.Text = "";
                    postcodeBox.Text = "";
                    teleBox.Text = "";
                    emailBox.Text = "";
                    passwordBox.Text = "";
                }
            }
            else if (childRadBtn.Checked)
            {
                SqlCommand ca = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO children(childID, firstname, dob, gender, password) VALUES (@childID, @firstname, @dob, @gender, @password)", connect);
                ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@childID", userBox.Text);
                ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstNameBox.Text);
                ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dayDobList.Text + monthDobList.Text + yearDobList.Text);
                ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", genderList.Text);
                ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordBox.Text);

                connect.Open();
                ca.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connect.Close();

                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                    userBox.Text = "";
                    firstNameBox.Text = "";
                    dayDobList.Text = "";
                    monthDobList.Text = "";
                    yearDobList.Text = "";
                    genderList.Text = "";
                    passwordBox.Text = "";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: lol @ `I can't stop my web app sending values to my database`.  It's become sentient!

Comment: `if...else` is 101 of programming.

Comment: I know it sounds ridiculous, it sounds better in my head. I know there is probably an alternative, less dumb way around it I just can't seem to find it!

Comment: Need to get a better grasp on how If/Else works.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx

Comment: Oh dear, how embarrassing.  I wish I could make Steve the answer, I missed out making the parent radio button else if. That fixed it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to work on the validation scheme, but I won't go into that as it is not what you asked.

You need to add an else case to the "if" that checks the boxes to prevent execution of the rest of the code:

```
if (firstNameBox.Text == "" || surnameBox.Text == "" || dayDobList.Text == "" || monthDobList.Text == "" || yearDobList.Text == "" || genderList.Text == "" || postcodeBox.Text == "" || teleBox.Text == "" || emailBox.Text == "" || userBox.Text == "" || passwordBox.Text == "")
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Please ensure all fields have an entry');</script>");
else
{
    //Put the rest of the code here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data  Source=THEBEAST;Initial Catalog=newregDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
    {
        if (firstNameBox.Text == "" || surnameBox.Text == "" || dayDobList.Text == "" || monthDobList.Text == "" || yearDobList.Text == "" || genderList.Text == "" || postcodeBox.Text == "" || teleBox.Text == "" || emailBox.Text == "" || userBox.Text == "" || passwordBox.Text == "")
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Please ensure all fields have an entry');</script>");
        else
        {
            if (parentRadBtn.Checked)
            {
                SqlCommand pa = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO parent(parentID, firstname, surname, postcode, telephone, email, password) VALUES (@parentID, @firstname, @surname, @postcode, @telephone, @email, @password)", connect);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parentID", userBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstNameBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", surnameBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", postcodeBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telephone", teleBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailBox.Text);
                pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordBox.Text);

                connect.Open();
                pa.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connect.Close();

                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                    userBox.Text = "";
                    firstNameBox.Text = "";
                    surnameBox.Text = "";
                    postcodeBox.Text = "";
                    teleBox.Text = "";
                    emailBox.Text = "";
                    passwordBox.Text = "";
                }
            }
            else if (childRadBtn.Checked)
            {
                SqlCommand ca = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO children(childID, firstname, dob, gender, password) VALUES (@childID, @firstname, @dob, @gender, @password)", connect);
                ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@childID", userBox.Text);
                ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstNameBox.Text);
                ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dayDobList.Text + monthDobList.Text + yearDobList.Text);
                ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", genderList.Text);
                ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordBox.Text);

                connect.Open();
                ca.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connect.Close();

                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                    userBox.Text = "";
                    firstNameBox.Text = "";
                    dayDobList.Text = "";
                    monthDobList.Text = "";
                    yearDobList.Text = "";
                    genderList.Text = "";
                    passwordBox.Text = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```